# Logitech G930 under Ubuntu (Crackling noises)

Tags: wireless, sound, headphones, logitech

I own the wireless headphone Logitech G930 and i have been using it under Windows without any problems. Unfortunately under Ubuntu (12.04 as well as 13.04) it has really poor audio quality: Crackling noises appear when i listen to music or even when i test the channels in the pulseaudio menu or when i play sounds.
When i plugged the transmitter in the headset gets recognized without any problems and is listed in the sound menu as Analog output.

I tested the system with also with the Speakers having no crackling noises so the problem has definitively to do with the G930.

I googled for quite a while now and i didnt find any solutions. There were even posts of people telling that they do not have problems at all.

Has anyone else the same issues as I do :(? Help very appreciated!

Thanks and bb

PinkYeti

EDIT: I Just tested it on Ubuntu 10.04 and there it seems to work fine. Did anything change in regard to the sound since 10.04? Is it possible to rollback concerning the sound?

Comment: I have the same problem as you, but I'm on 13.10.  Still no solution though.  Will update here if I find anything.

Comment: Do you experience these noises too without PulseAudio directly over ALSA? You can test that with `speaker-test -D [DEVICE] -c [CHANNELS] -twav` and find the device name with `aplay -L`, which should be something like `sourround71`. You may need to kill PulseAudio just before to get it to work with `pulseaudio -k; speaker-test [...]`.